# nothing happens when I attempt to textout to a transparent image

Tags: lazarus

I am using Lazarus.
I have put 2 images on a form and synchronized their positions and sizes.
I can textout to both images, and after I made the ontop image transparent I can see the combined content of both images.
I can add further text to the bottom image and see it, but I can't see text I try to add to the transparent image.
I used the following code to make the top image transparent

```
image2.picture.Bitmap.TransparentColor:=clWhite;
image2.transparent:=true;
```

I guess I need to play with the image bitmap, but I can't find a solution that is not using other software.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Overlaying two image controls is probably the wrong solution. Much better would be to use a paintbox control and compose the entire image in the `OnPaint` event.

Comment: If the image is transparent, the alpha value of each transparent pixel is probably 0. TextOut, if it uses something like GDI, does not change the top byte, so your image gets text, but it is still transparent. TransparentColor is for normal bitmaps. It defines one colour in the palette of that bitmap that is to be masked out and display as transparent. It has nothing to do with truly or per-pixel-transparent bitmaps.